# Responsive footer cannot be at the bottom of page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my footer be at the bottom of the page (but not fixed) with bootstrap but it does not seem to be working. There seems to be some kind of spacing between it and the bottom of the page.

Here's an example of my issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/whywymam/hj22ggep/

```
.footer {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.footer li {
    display: inline;
}
.copyright {
    margin-top: 1%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-bottom footer" role="navigation">
  <div class="footer">
            <ul>
            <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a> | </li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">&nbsp; Contact Us</a> |</li> 
            <li><a href="terms&condition.php">&nbsp; Term of Use</a></li>
            </ul>
            <p class="copyright"> All Rights Reserved</p>
        </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you make some fiddle? Because right now I see no footer at all, just simple nav element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` to position it down the page. `margin-bottom: 0` to remove the bottom space. Try to avoid !important and use the additional CSS after all CSS code.

```css
.footer {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute !important;;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
.footer li {
  display: inline;
}
.copyright {
  margin-top: 1%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-bottom footer" role="navigation">

  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a> |</li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">&nbsp; Contact Us</a> |</li>
      <li><a href="terms&condition.php">&nbsp; Term of Use</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <p class="copyright">All Rights Reserved</p>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the css

```
.footer{
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 100%;
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
}
```

you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/qy4vujyf/

Answer (score 0):

View **[LIVE](http://jsfiddle.net/2bhbrvx3/1/)**

#### CSS

```
.footer {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.container {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width: inherit;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.footer li {
    display: inline;
}
.copyright {
    margin-top: 1%;
}
```